# replacing each words in sentence into the words index using python

Tags: python, string, pandas, csv, str-replace

I have two csv files one contain sentences as shown:

```
                         sentences
0  yes good bye how should and bye
1                       bye should
2                         good bye
```

and another csv which has each word and its index next to it as shown:

```
     word  frequency  index
0     and        500     10
1     you        334      1
2     how        320      2
3  should        250      3
4     yes        100      4
5     bye         50      5
6    good          1      6
```

I'm trying to use Dictionary as a solution for my problem but it prints strange output just for one word instead of the whole sentence

```
import string
import pandas as pd
text=pd.read_csv("one.csv")

change=pd.read_csv("result.csv")
print(text)
update = dict(zip(change.word, change.index))
print(update)
text1 = text['sentences'].replace(update, regex=True)
print(text1)
text1.to_csv('yes.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Im expecting the output to be:

**4 6 5 2 3 10 5**

**5 3**

**6 5**

I'm getting this output instead:

[image]

what am I doing wrong any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`series.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) for all items after splitting each row:

```
s=df2.set_index('word')['index']
final=df1.assign(index=[[s.get(a) for a in i.split()] for i in df1['sentences']])
```

---

```
                         sentences                   index
0  yes good bye how should and bye  [4, 6, 5, 2, 3, 10, 5]
1                       bye should                  [5, 3]
2                         good bye                  [6, 5]
```

Comment: but this is printing the sentences as well how to make it print just the index ?

Comment: are you fine it it prints a list? if you want them as string check @ansev answer

Comment: yes I converted the list back to a dataframe to store it into a CSV file again because lists dont have **to.csv** option

Answer (score 2):

We can use a series to replace,
on the other hand the key seems to convert the Series to str with [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
text['index']=text.sentences.replace(change.set_index('word')['index']
                                           .astype(str),
                                     regex = True)
print(text)
#text.sentences.replace(change.set_index('word')['index'],regex = True)
#0    10
#1     3
#2     5
#Name: sentences, dtype: int64
```

**Output**

```
                         sentences           index
0  yes good bye how should and bye  4 6 5 2 3 10 5
1                       bye should             5 3
2                         good bye             6 5
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but yours is converting it to a string I will be feeding the numbers into a neural network it might cause a problem for me

Comment: Then the @ anky_91 solution will do well :). 

We could suggest using explode if you want to get rid of the list. `final.explode('index')`.
Although if the list is not an impediment, it could be a mistake to increase the number of rows

Comment: thank you for the advice I will look into explode as well